# Automapper/StructureMap issues with TPL version of synchronous code

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, automapper, structuremap

This is my synchronous working version for some workers to do some different work given a generic workload:

```
foreach (var worker in _workers)
{
    worker.DoWork(workload);
}
```

I am trying to exploit existing cores via the task parallel library (TPL) using this:

```
foreach (var worker in _workers)
{
    var worker1 = worker;
    await Task.Run(() => worker1.DoWork(workload));
}
await Task.WhenAll();
```

The intention is, that each worker is executed in its own thread. Please note that this runs in a async method, which receives a 'workload' from time to time. I want to ensure that all work is done before the foreach is run again. Hence, the line:

```
await Task.WhenAll();
```

Unfortunately I seem to have some sporadic mapping exception related to automapper/structuremap (it works fine synchronously). This is my structuremap code:

```
public class MyRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyRegistry()
    {
        For<ISomething>().Singleton().Use<SomethingConcrete>();

        var profiles =
        from t in typeof(MyRegistry).Assembly.GetTypes()
        where typeof(Profile).IsAssignableFrom(t)
        select (Profile)Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            cfg.AddProfile(profile);
        }
        });

        For<MapperConfiguration>().Use(config);
        For<IMapper>().Use(ctx => ctx.GetInstance<MapperConfiguration>().CreateMapper(ctx.GetInstance));
    }
}
```

To isolate the problem, is there something fundamentally wrong with the TPL code to start with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there something fundamentally wrong with the TPL code?

Yes. `await Task.WhenAll()` doesn't do anything as it's supposed to accept tasks as parameters. And offloading to the `ThreadPool` with `Task.Run` but awaiting each task sequentially doesn't either.

What you probably wanted to do is this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var worker in _workers)
{
    tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => worker.DoWork(workload)));
}

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or more simply this:

```
await Task.WhenAll(_workers.Select(worker => Task.Run(() => worker .DoWork(workload)));
```

Which creates a task for each worker that will run on the `ThreadPool` and then uses `Task.WhenAll` to await the completion of all these tasks.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a go. Is there a grantee that every task is run in a dedicated thread? If not, is there a way to ensure that?

Comment: @csetzkorn each will run on its own thread. But not necessarily at the same time. If you want more control you need to mange the threads yourself instead of relying on the `ThreadPool`

Comment: Thanks. That's OK. I just need to ensure that the foreach loop is only started after all workers have finished. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I tried this. Still getting occasional/unexplained automapper exceptions. Not sure whay as synchronous version works fine ...